# Count Tree Leaves Concurrently

Tags: go, recursion, channel, goroutine

There is a function that I want to write using a concurrency model in case the input is too large and parallel processing would be more efficient but it never ends.

Assuming there is a `struct` defined as:

```
type Tree struct {
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    SubTrees []*Tree  `json:"subTrees,omitempty"`
    Leaves   []string `json:"leaves"`
}
```

I want to write a function that calculates the total number of `Leaves` throughout the entire recursive structure. This is easily done with recursion with:

```
func (tree *Tree) CountLeaves() int {
    curr := len(tree.Leaves)
    for _, s := range tree.SubTrees {
        curr += s.CountLeaves()
    }
    return curr
}
```

That's nice and all, but if the structure becomes too large, this is going to be inefficient so I wanted to refactor it to be concurrent and use channels. Here is my attempt at the refactor:

```
func (tree *Tree) CountLeaves() int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int)
    defer close(ch)
    go count(tree, true, ch, &wg)

    var total int
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(total *int) {
        for x := range ch {
            fmt.Println(x)
            *total += x
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(&total)
    wg.Wait()

    return total
}

func count(t *Tree, root bool, ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- len(t.Leaves)
    if t.SubTrees != nil {
        wg.Add(len(t.SubTrees))
        for _, s := range t.SubTrees {
            go count(s, false, ch, wg)
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }

    if root {
        ch <- -1
    }
}
```

I am able to currently gather all numbers through the channel that I would need to currently calculate the total number of `Leaves` but the function never ends. The terminating value `-1` from the root `Tree` struct is never pushed or received through the channel and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this faster ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I did a speed comparison with the standard recursive function with a `node_modules` folder because that's a black hole of files and the concurrent model was neck-and-neck with the recursive model, so it appears there's no real benefit right now

Comment: yeah, the work you have paralelized is too small to get any benefits in regards of the number of added contention. I suspect that if you have very very large tree, having only two/four routine counting different major branches might give better results. sorry for the preliminary fake question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your `WaitGroup` is just never getting enough `wg.Done` calls:

```
go func(total *int) {
    for x := range ch {
        fmt.Println(x)
        *total += x
    }
    wg.Done()
}(&total)
```

Since you never close `ch`, the `wg.Done` will never be called here.  I *think* if you move it inside the loop:

```
go func(total *int) {
    for x := range ch {
        fmt.Println(x)
        *total += x
         wg.Done()
    }
}(&total)
```

That will resolve the issue.

EDIT:

Actually, I think there is one more issue:

```
defer wg.Done()
ch <- len(t.Leaves)
if t.SubTrees != nil {
    wg.Add(len(t.SubTrees))
    for _, s := range t.SubTrees {
        go count(s, false, ch, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

The defered `wg.Done()` won't get called until you return, so this `wg.Wait()` will also wait forever.  This hsould probable be:

```
ch <- len(t.Leaves)
if t.SubTrees != nil {
    wg.Add(len(t.SubTrees))
    for _, s := range t.SubTrees {
        go count(s, false, ch, wg)
    }
    wg.Done()
    wg.Wait()
} else {
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: moving the `wg.Done()` call for the accumulator inside the loop would treat each iteration as a separate goroutine which isn't the case. It would give a negative counter for the WaitGroup

Comment: The suggestions in your edit worked for the most part, but I have inconsistent performance because of the way that i `defer close(ch)`. Is that unnecessary?

Comment: I ended up having to place `close(ch)` inside a separate closure with the initial call to `count` and now its consistent